Делаю авторизацию через получение кода в СМС, на стадии ввода цифр далее алгоритм не срабатывает,
Делаю авторизацию через получение кода в СМС, на стадии ввода цифр далее алгоритм не срабатывает, не пойму на какой стадии написания кода ошибка. я уже два дня мучаюсь, не могу понять ничего.
Работаю в Андроид Студио Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1 Build #AI-232.10300.40.2321.11567975, built on March 13, 2024
class EnterCodeFragment(private val phoneNumber: String, val id: String) : Fragment() {



private var _mBinding: FragmentEnterCodeBinding? = null
private val mBinding get() = _mBinding!!


override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater,
container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
_mBinding = FragmentEnterCodeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
return mBinding.root
}

override fun onStart() {
super.onStart()
(activity as RegisterActivity).title = phoneNumber
mBinding.registerInputCode.addTextChangedListener(AppTextWatcher {
    val string = mBinding.registerInputCode.text.toString()
    if (string.length >= 6) {
        enterCode()
    }
})
}

private fun enterCode() {
val code: String = mBinding.registerInputCode.text.toString()
val credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(id, code)
AUTH.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        showToast("Добро пожаловать")
        (activity as RegisterActivity).replaceActivity(MainActivity())
    } else showToast(task.exception?.message.toString())
}
}

введите сюда код


Как вы предлагаете вам помочь, если этот код невозможно запустить без проекта целиком и в чём выражается его "нерабочесть" вы не объяснили. Если вы не можете локализовать место ошибки - учитесь делать отладку, без этого навыка заниматься разработкой невозможно.

Пишите в лог что вводите, потом что отправляете и что приходит в ответ. Уже из этих трех значений можно будет начинать строить догадки. А то "алгоритм не срабатывает" - это как-то совсем для экстрасенсов.

@EugeneKrivenja  Да в том и проблема что я не понимаю.  Ошибок в логах нет, просто проходит авторизация в файрбазе, я установил приложение на телефон, мне приходит смс с кодом авторизации, но вот обратно оно в фаербазу для аутотентификации не уходит. я не могу понять почему так.

@EugeneKrivenja  нашел проблему, в логах показывает ошибку Ime callback not found. Ignoring unregisterReceivedCallback. callbackId: 218145719
